# Recode Numeric To Character

Tags: r, data.table, recode

```
have = data.frame("v1" = c(1,2,3))
want = data.frame("v1" = c("pass", "arb", "rtk"))
```

I want to recode the numeric to these strings. My attempts at data.table fails:

```
library(data.table)
have[, c("v1") := recode(v1, 1 == "pass", 2=="arb", 3=="rtk")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'v1' can be used as an index as it is a sequence of values from 1.  So, if we pass the new vector to rename in the order we want, then 'pass' will replace whereever there is 1 value in 'v1', 'arb' for 2 and 'rtk' for 3

```
library(data.table)
setDT(have)[, v1 := c('pass', 'arb', 'rtk')[v1]]
```

Another option is using a named vector to do the match

```
nm1 <- setNames(c('pass', 'arb', 'rtk'),  1:3)
setDT(have)[, v1 := nm1[as.character(v1)]]
```

---

Or do this with a `factor` `label` option

```
setDT(have)[, v1 := as.character(factor(v1, levels = 1:3, 
           labels = c('pass', 'arb', 'rtk')))]
```

---

In the OP's code, the `recode` is using comparison operator (`==`), instead it would be `=`.  Also, for values that are numeric, wrap with backquote

```
setDT(have)[, v1  := dplyr::recode(v1, `1` = "pass", `2`="arb", `3`="rtk")]
```

Comment: this is working perfect. i wonder is there any way to specify the '1' equals to pass just in case somebody else looks at the codes?

Comment: @bvowe I updated some more methods

Comment: @bvowe the `recode` you used I assume is from `dplyr`.  Please check my updated code